# What is the function of the ID in the xml file

Tags: android, xml, cordova, google-play, phonegap-desktop-app

I made an app using **PhoneGap**, and in the beginning I could fill in an ID, this was optional however so I just left it to the standard one, not knowing what is was.

When I tried to upload the app to the play-store I had to change the ID to some not existing ID. I went ahead and changed the ID in the **config.xml** file to a reverse domain name, as they advised.

But still my question remains:

- What is the function of the ID? and
- Why should it be a reverse domain name?

I of course did some research before asking, but I could find very little on this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/):

> id: the unique identifier for your application. To support all
>   supported platforms, this must be reverse-domain name style (e.g.
>   com.yourcompany.yourapp)

This is to make your app unique in the playstore. To avoid naming collisions between app in the play store.

Read more about [Reverse domain name notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_domain_name_notation)
.